# Purpose of Haystack

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-haystack

Can anyone help me to do know about haystack? I have read about it in the official website. But I can't get it clearly what they do in it and in which purpose it will be used. Explain me about it with the example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Haystack provides modular search for Django. It allows you to search on top of search backends (such as Solr, Elasticsearch, Whoosh, Xapian, etc.)

It features a unified, familiar API that allows you to plug in different search backends without having to modify your code.

Read Docs [Here](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for more info